# How to sum multiple BCD numbers in assembly?

Tags: assembly, 68000, bcd

I am coding this in Motorola68k simulator.
I want my program to execute this task:

- (Address of first element of linked list is saved on address $6000 (longword) followed by length of the list (word) and final result (word))
- Go through linked list (every element of list is containing address of next element (longword) followed by BCD number (byte))
- Sum all BCD numbers of linked list and save the sum in RESULT.

I understand how to go through each element of the list but I'm struggling to add BCD numbers. I want to add in each iteration to numbers and store them in D6, then at the end put D6 in RESULT. Here is my code:

```
DATA:           EQU     $1500
PROG:           EQU     $1000
LIST:           EQU     $6000

LEN:            EQU     $1500    ;lenght of BCD numbers (all are .B)
NUM1:           EQU     $1510
NUM2:           EQu     $1520

                ORG     LISTA
FIRST           DS.L    1
LENGHT          DS.W    1
RESULT          DS.W    1

                ORG PROG

START:      
                MOVE.L  FIRST, A0
                MOVE.W  LENGHT, D1
                MOVEQ   #0, D2
                MOVEQ   #0, D6
                CLR.W   RESULT
SUM_LOOP:
                CMP.W   #0, D1
                BEQ     DONE
            
                MOVEQ   #0, D3
            
                MOVE.L  (A0)+, A1
                MOVE.B  (A0), D3
                MOVE.B  D3, NUM1
            
                MOVE.L  A1, A0
                MOVE.L  (A1)+, A1
                MOVE.B  (A1), D5
                MOVE.B  D5, NUM2

                CLR.W   D4
                MOVE.B  #1, LEN
                MOVE.B  LEN, D4
                MOVE.W  D4, A5
                LEA NUM1(A5), A3
                LEA NUM2(A5), A4

                SUBQ    #1, D4
                MOVE    #0, CCR

 LOOP:      
                ABCD.B  -(A4), -(A3)
                DBRA    D4, LOOP

                ADD.L   NUM1, D6

                SUBQ.W  #1, D1
                BRA     SUM_LOOP
 DONE:
                MOVE.W  D6, RESULT

                MOVE.B  #9,D0
                TRAP    #15 ; halt simulator

                END  START
```

Comment: Set one register to zero, add the first value to that register, add the second value to that register, etc.? In short, just iterate over the list, adding each value one by one to the destination register. Once done, move the value in the register to the final destination variable.

Comment: http://meseec.ce.rit.edu/eecc250-winter99/250-1-20-2000.pdf BCD on 68000

Comment: Where do you get the length (i.e. number of bytes) in each BCD element of the linked list nodes?  Is it given at each node, or by the list, or known as a constant at build time (e.g. 1)?

Comment: @ErikEidt all BCD numbers are the same length  .B

Comment: Length of 1 byte?  If so, then after you've added them all together, looks like you need to convert to proper binary, which means extract the upper nibble as a number and multiply it by 10, then add the lower nibble.  That's fort the conversion from BCD to regular binary number.

Comment: Otherwise, suggest getting each BCD byte and accumulating into a result register, using `ABCD Dn, Dn`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That won't work for BCD. You have to do it one by one, and take care of the carries.